# C# AES RijndaelManaged() CBC and PaddingMode.Zeros seems to miss 16 chars after post to PHP JSON

Tags: c#, php

I have a C# server posting to a php server.  Exactly 16 characters are missing from the beginning of the JSON string on the PHP side. Now the PHP decryption looks like this:

```
function Decrypt($data_base64)
{
    global $key;
    global $iv_size;

    $ciphertext_dec = base64_decode($data_base64);

    $iv_dec = substr($ciphertext_dec, 0, $iv_size);
    $ciphertext_dec = substr($ciphertext_dec, $iv_size);

    $plaintext_utf8_dec = mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $key,
        $ciphertext_dec, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $iv_dec);

    return  $plaintext_utf8_dec;
}
```

And the C# post:

```
        aesCrypt = new RijndaelManaged();
        aesCrypt.KeySize = 256;
        aesCrypt.BlockSize = 128;
        aesCrypt.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
        aesCrypt.Padding = PaddingMode.Zeros;

        var started = new StartStopObject() { action = "online" };
        string jsonser1 = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(started);
        Post(Encrypt(jsonser1));

    private string Encrypt(string plainStr)
    {
        aesCrypt.GenerateIV();
        byte[] encrypted;
        ICryptoTransform crypto = aesCrypt.CreateEncryptor(aesCrypt.Key, aesCrypt.IV);
        using (System.IO.MemoryStream msEncrypt = new System.IO.MemoryStream())
        using (CryptoStream csEncrypt = new CryptoStream(msEncrypt, crypto, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
        {
            using (System.IO.StreamWriter swEncrypt = new System.IO.StreamWriter(csEncrypt))
            {
                swEncrypt.Write(plainStr);
            }
            encrypted = msEncrypt.ToArray();
        }
        return Convert.ToBase64String(encrypted);
    }

    public void Post(string data)
    {
        byte[] buffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("var1=" + data);
        HttpWebRequest WebReq = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(posturl);
        WebReq.Method = "POST";
        WebReq.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        WebReq.ContentLength = buffer.Length;
        System.IO.Stream PostData = WebReq.GetRequestStream();
        PostData.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        PostData.Close();
    }
```

A vardump and echo in the PHP shows:

array(1) {
  ["var1"]=>
  string(128) "UahqVaE2nrxrTAijsZmjXL8QF9YmcRXdcRUREaFp7LKlhy6StrXqMc7TDmCF4qRT8fZZOZ5ovY/vHySzP2u73cs66i7nG1ywXrGiZOHa4E9yiOFFruQegIy/6yqiPXf9"
}
e","email":null,"realm":null,"script":null,"followtag":null,"autojoin":null}

As you can see exactly 16 chars are missing from the beginning of the JSON string. ( {"action":"online","email":null,"realm":null,"script":null,"followtag":null,"autojoin":null} )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CryptoStream doesn't automatically prepend the IV to the ciphertext. The PHP side is chopping off the first block of the message and using that as the IV.

Here's some sample PHP that reproduces the problem:

```
$ivSize = 32;

$key = hash('SHA256', 'hello world', true);
$iv = mcrypt_create_iv($ivSize);

$cipher = mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $key,
   "This is some sample text where the first block will be cut off.", MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $iv);

$firstBlock = substr($cipher, 0, $ivSize);
$remainingCipher = substr($cipher, $ivSize);

$plain = mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $key, $remainingCipher, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $firstBlock);
echo $plain;
```

Outputs:

```
he first block will be cut off.
```

Comment: im pretty sure initing the ICryptoTransform with the IV prepends it regardless I added some Array.Copy's to build the array with the IV key prepended and it gives an error  <b>Warning</b>:  mcrypt_decrypt(): The IV parameter must be as long as the blocksize in <b>/var/www/html/controlserv/engine/crypt.php</b> on line <b>28</b><br />

Comment: What are you using for $iv_size? It's been a while since I did crypto stuff in C# but I have a distinct memory of having to prepend the IV myself. I also don't see anything about it doing that automatically in the docs.

Comment: it seems to be URI encoding might be playing a part. I notice that the string only comes out with the 16 chars missing if it does not contain any '+' or '='  otherwise the post sends them as spaces and php reads them as blank spaces totally messing up the decryption making it all unrecognizable.  I cannot add System.Web to my project because we are using the client profile.  $iv_size is 16.  If it chopped off the first block as the IV how can it even decrypt the rest of it? it should totally be mangled no?

Comment: k I think were getting somewhere prepending the IV in C# and it seems better i can see the first 16 now but if theres a + sign in the string its all messed up after the + sign as it gets translated into a space on the PHP side..

EDIT: data = data.Replace("+", "%2B");   hacky but ffff it